# How can I change activity:label when starting another activity

Tags: android, android-manifest

I´m learning Android Studio and what I want to do is to change the label or title displayed at the top of the activity depending on the activity on the screen.

When I change from MainActivity to SecondActivity, the label is the same and I want "SecondActivity" to be displayed at the top.

Answer (score 0):

change the toolbar name, try do this in your second activity:

```
mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);            
setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My new title");
```

Comment: Eduardo. I did this in the AndroidManifest file and seems to work fine, is this recommended? I had to create a new string (strings.xml) and then set the label attribute                                                                                                         <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/second_activity" />